# Using a loop to compare strings in Python

Tags: python, string, sorting, loops

I have this assignment to create a program that asks for a user to enter a series of names, then after the last name is entered it should display the first and last alphabetical names. I was told not to use an array as well.

I was thinking I should use a loop to bring the user back to the input part of the program, but I am having trouble setting up the conditions of the loop to compare the strings. This is what I have so far:

```
NAME_LIST = int(4)

nameCount <= NAME_LIST

for nameCount in range(1, NAME_LIST):
    names = int(input('Please enter a name: ')
```

I wanted to use four names in the program

Comment: 1) No need for `int(4)` Python knows that you want a int when you say `NAME_LIST=4` 2) Use a list with `names=list()` before the loop and then use `names.append(input('Please enter a name: ')` inside the loop 3) then use `sorted(names)` to get the sorted list. Only use `input` on Python 3; otherwise use `raw_input` Done! You are ready for your IPO!!!

Comment: do you mean the first and last in sorted alphabetical order?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not using an array? What are you not allowed to use an array for? Does that include lists, dicts and generators? Also does *told not to* mean that it isn't allowed or that whoever did the telling doesn't think you should?

Comment: Its an intro to logic course and he has us using Python after he covers it in the book...The list works well, I just have to compare each name now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you use a loop, and for each iteration, you calculate the first and
last names.

Once all the names have been iterated, you have the first and last names
across the whole input.

```
NAME_LIST = 4

first_name = ""
last_name  = ""

for nameCount in range(NAME_LIST):
    name = raw_input('Please enter a name: ').title()
    first_name = first_name or name
    first_name = min(first_name, name)
    last_name  = max(last_name, name)

print("First: %s" % first_name)
print("Last: %s" % last_name)
```

Comment: You could use `first_name = "~"` to get a string that sorts after any reasonable name, then you wouldn't need the `firstname or name` bit. I'd also suggest a less misleading variable name than `NAME_LIST` (which isn't a list).

Comment: @Blckknght, that's true about `first_name` initialisation but I didn't want to have 'magic' values (given OP is a newbie). As for `NAME_LIST`, I agree but I tried to keep the code as close as possible to OPs, for their understanding.